# How do I recreate or move a logo from Photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I created a logo for my company from an photo in Photoshop and now I would like to move it to Illustrator to make it a vector image so I can make professional looking marketing material. Can someone walk me through this process?

Many thanks.

Comment: Unless you used to vector paths in Photoshop, there's not an "easy way" to do this. You'll have to put in the work and just do it again in Illustrator.

Comment: It'd really help if you can show us the image you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The principal is quite simple, but it may be time-consuming depending of what is at stack in your logo:

- Import your "<strike>matrix</strike> raster version" of your logo in a new Illustrator document.
- Use it as a model above which you will recreate the "vector version" of your logo using standard Illustrator tools.
- In some cases, vectorization function can make you save time as a rough work first step, or for some particular parts of the logo content.

Comment: "matrix" version?

Comment: In French, we can say "image matricielle" vs "image vectorielle", maybe I did not translate it well or the term is only known in signal processing field. For instance, PSD, JPG, BMP, PNG are matrix images, since the content is described as a matrix of pixels.

Comment: Its called a raster image or bitmap image if you want to accentuate that is made out of pixels even pixel image. But usually you dont need to.

Comment: Ah, figured that's what you meant but never heard it referred like that except in "dot matrix printing." In English we'd call those Raster. Except PSD since that's not really Raster/Matrix or Vector.

Comment: I will go for "raster". "bitmap" is confusing since it can refer to the Microsoft file format. By the way, the word "matricielle" is used in [this article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap) on Wikipedia. On the English equivalent article, the translation is "raster graphics" indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You may need more instruction on using Adobe Illustrator tools, but to get started, here is one way to go about this:

1. Place the .PSD file into AI (File > Place).
2. Double click on the layer icon in the Layers Panel. Re-name the layer TEMPLATE and select the Template check box and the dialog box while renaming. This will lock the layer and dim the image to a percentage you can specify.

[image]

3. Create a new layer on top of the TEMPLATE layer to begin using the Adobe Illustrator tools to replicate the logo you created in Photoshop.